# how to iterate over Single<List> and map to another list?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-android, rx-java2

as a result of retrofit request I get `Single<List<Info>>` I should iterate over each item and based on the each item id should call another request  which also is Single AND then map to DetailInfo
and as a result to have `Single<List<DetailInfo>>`

I found flattenAsObservable  and flattenAsFlowable ,
I'm not sure to use it is the right approach, if yes I have another problem I receive `Single<List<Single<DetailInfo>>` while I need to have `Single<List<DetailInfo>>`

```
fun recipeInfos(id: Long) {
 return repository.recipeInfos(id)
  .flattenAsObservable { it ->
    it.map { it ->it.id }
  }.map { id ->repository.detail(id)
  .map { detailInfo -> detailInfo.toModel() }}
  .toList()
}
```

Comment: You really only need one map operator to get `it -> repository.detail(it.id).toModel()`

Comment: @cricket_007 but in map it is the list and I could not have an access to it.id

Comment: I meant this one. `it.map { it ->it.id }`... Anyways, if you have a list, you need something like `flatMap`

Comment: I think flatMap could not work here, 
and I could have 1 map 
as repository.detail() returns Single<DetailInfo> while toModel is function of DetailInfo

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed `.map { id ->repository.detail(id)` to

```
.flatMap { id ->repository.detail(id)}
```

and it works